# Not able to see debug values in quick watch or in Add watch or when i move mouse pointer over the variable, for C++ project in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-c++

I am having a C++ project build using vs2015. The problem is when I debug the application created,  I put few break points and started debugging., 
 it was hitting the brake point, step into and step over is working, 
 but the values are not getting shown up when 
 I move the mouse over the variables. and in "Add watch" or "quick watch" for the variable, it says Internal error in the expression evaluator.

Any suggestion 
Thanks
Arjun Reddy

Comment: same project my friends able to debug. same settings, everything same, I checked debugging settings in options, and I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Make sure you have debug symbols enabled.

Comment: debug symbols are enabled, I checked it.

Comment: Have you enabled symbol server in VS options?